# Prove that $nCr = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)/ 1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdots r$ is an integer for all positive integral $n$ and for all integers $r \geq 0$.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinations

Prove that $nCr =\frac{ n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)}{ 1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdots r}$, is an
integer for all positive integral values of $n$ and for all
integers $r \geq 0$.

Can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: How can you construct $1.2.3 \dots r$ since $r \leq 0$ ???

Comment: $r$ must be positive and $r \le n.$

Answer (score 2):

If $r=0$ then $nC0=1$.  If $r=n$ thn $nCn=1$.
Otherwise, can you show that $nCr=(n-1)Cr+(n-1)C(r-1)$.  It takes a little calculation, but there is a lot of common factors.
If all the $(n-1)Cr$ are integers, then all the $nCr$ must be integers too.